# The most concise and elegant way to break the reactivity of helpers in meteor

Tags: collections, meteor, helper

I want to use my collection players in an helper... for several reasons I would like this collection will be not reactive. I would like just a first call  to the database to display the collection. I tried to use reactivates:false option but in this case the collection remains empty after loading and nothing display.

```
 Template.myGame.helpers({
      players: function () {
        return Players.find({}, {reactive: false});
      }
    })


<ul>
  {{#each players}}
    {{> player}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively looking for a way to return data non-reactively, but only once it's ready.  This can be achieved with a subscription handle (assuming you've removed "autopublish").

```
playersSub = Meteor.subscribe('players', ...);

Template.myGame.helpers({
  players: function() {
    if (playersSub.ready()) {
      return Players.find({}, {reactive: false});
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
});
```

NB - it is actually possible to get the subscription readiness (non-reactively) without having a handle, by using `Players._connection._subscriptions.[SUB_ID].ready`, but I wouldn't recommend this as it's not part of the public API.